# Download all tables and stored procedures to file

Tags: sql-server

is it possible to download in a file all the table definition(create Statements) and Stored

Procedures from a SQL Server 2008 database?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, right click on the database-->tasks-->generate scripts

This will bring up the scripting wizard, pick the objects you want and specify output

See also: [How To Script Out The Whole Database In SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-to-script-out-the-whole-database-in--2008)

Comment: great you saved me hours of boring copy and paste